# how to select one column from table one , while passing a value of column from table two?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have two tables partner_routing and partner. I am trying to select the routingId from partner_routing table while trying to satisfy the condition that the partner id in both the tables is same and the client id from partner_info id will be given as input

```
SELECT partnerRouting.routingId 
FROM partner_routing partnerRouting, partner_info partner
WHERE partner.partner_id=partnerRouting.partnerId 
  AND partner.clientId=1
  AND partnerRouting.deleted = 0;

SELECT routingId 
FROM partner_routing partnerRouting, partner_info partner
WHERE partner.partner_id = partnerRouting.partnerId 
  AND partnerRouting.deleted = 0
  AND partner.clientId IN (
   SELECT clientId FROM partner_info partner WHERE partner.clientId = 1
  );

SELECT routingId
FROM partner_routing partnerRouting
  INNER JOIN partner_info partner ON partner.partner_id = partnerRouting.partnerId
WHERE partnerRouting.deleted = 0
  AND partner.clientId = 1;
```

I did not get the desired result with the above... if i remove the partner.clientId = 1 part then i am getting the result, but i do need to filter the results based on the client id in partner_info table. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well use INNER JOIN for this

```
SELECT partner_routing.routingId 
FROM partner_routing INNER JOIN partner_info 
ON partner_routing.partner_id = partner_info.partner_id
WHERE partner_info.clientId=1
```

You are using wrong syntax for INNER JOIN, use below syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp for more information.

Comment: @user2495876: was this helpful ?